# extend interfaces to be a dictionary

Tags: typescript

I have an angular resource interface which I would like to extend to get the object structure from the backend. It works everywhere for any interface type except for dictionaries:

```
export interface MyInterface extends angular.resource.IResource<any> {
  [key: string]: MyAnotherInterface;
}
```

Typescript compiler gives an error that all attributes from `angular.resource.IResource` cannot be found because as I understand this another declaration `[key: string]: MyAnotherInterface;` overwrites all the properties of extendable unit. So, again as I understand, the problem is that the dictionary declaration is very strict and does not allow other properties on the same interface.

I cannot change the structure which is returned by the server (and it is silly to change it just because of TS); meanwhile I really wish to avoid writing every time `(<any>MyInterface).myProperty` - this really smells.

TypeScript version: 1.7.5

How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, again as I understand, the problem is that the dictionary declaration is very strict and does not allow other properties on the same interface

Yes. You cannot have a dictionary Indexible by `string` in which some properties do not conform to the *general* structure (your `MyAnotherInterface`).

> I cannot change the structure which is returned by the server (and it is silly to change it just because of TS);

You can do something like this:

```
export interface MyInterface extends angular.resource.IResource<any> {
  get(key:string): MyAnotherInterface;
}
```

And then add the `get` function as simply `(instance as any).get = (x:string)=>this[x];`

Comment: thank you for response. The function `get` should be added to every object, right?